# Service to Clean / Organize Data from Web Service Before MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rest

I have XML data feeds coming from multiple 3rd party sources and I would like some sort of middleware that is easily configurable that can clean and reorganize the data for our own mySQL server.

Notes:

1. the XML format may or may not be different for each client
2. we have a PHP RESTful API with a Backbone frontend

Is there a plug and play solution?
Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: You question is really, really really broad. There is [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) which might be what you're looking for. It's not PHP but Java, in any case, I *think* you should take that. In the PHP world there is nothing comparable AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer more specifically without more details in the question, but if you want to store data from multiple XML sources in a unified and way, your best best would be to pull out the data you need, serialize as JSON, and store as TEXT in your MySQL database using PDO prepared queries.

This would allow you to pull the relevant data from each feed (even keeping all of it) and create an object that makes sense to your app. Use PHP's json_encode() method on the object to serialize it, then add it to your table as a data field — be sure to store additional fields like source, date_created, etc so you know what to do with it when you pull it out.

Added bonuses: using a prepared PDO query will protect a bit against bad input from a third-party feed, and storing in JSON will give you something you can give directly to your Backbone-based front-end.

Comment: What are your thoughts on a robust solution like Apache Camel(mentioned above)? more trouble than its worth or something that would be scalable for me?

Comment: Well there's not really much detail in the question, but unless there's a lot more than simply fetching feeds and caching/storing the data then I wouldn't add another language and app to the stack. PHP has really solid XML parsing built in ([http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php)) and JSON is a great universal standard. You might have needs beyond this and you'll need to weigh those against your app.